# @Output() EventEmitter Not Working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, eventemitter

I try to make a `see more` button to get more search results at the moment of clicking.

I have my header in separate arrchivos and I use it with:

```
<ion-header>
  <page-header> </page-header>
</ion-header>
```

For each view.

The button that generates the event is in a `search-modal.html` like this:

```
  <div (click)="seeMoreResults($event)">
    <button color="primary" block>see more</button>
  </div>
```

And the `search-modal.ts` controller looks like this:

```
Import {Component, EventEmitter, Output} from '@ angular / core';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-search-modal',
  templateUrl: 'search-modal.html',
})
export class SearchModalPage {

@Output()
public updateSearchResults = new EventEmitter();

seeMoreResults(event) {
    this.countSearchResult = Object.keys( this.searchResult ).length; // "this.searchResult" are the search results that arrive when something is typed.
    this.updateSearchResults.emit( this.countSearchResult );
}
```

The `header.html` has this:

```
<ion-toolbar (updateSearchResults)='updateSearchResults($event)'>
// Here is my search bar.
</ion-toolbar>
```

And my `header.ts` has:

```
updateSearchResults(lastTotal){
  this.search((10+lastTotal), lastTotal, true);
  // "search" is the method that makes me search and issues the result.
}
```

The first search is working fine, that's why I omitted the code.
But when I click the "see more" button it does not emit anything, I tried to put a `console.log("Run");` inside `updateSearchResults` of `header.ts` but never prints.

Any idea why it is?

***Sorry for the translation, I speak Spanish.***

Comment: Did something happen to your code while copy-pasting? There seems to be a lot of extra spaces, some of them syntax errors.

Comment: Is the emitting component the immediate child of the receiving component? Angular events only up one level?

Comment: The code has been modified by the translation I made using google. I am sorry. But I checked the syntax in my code and everything is fine. I'm going to copy directly from my code to here. I will comment when this is done.

Comment: Ok, I already copied the code.

Answer (score 0):

The `(updateSearchResults)` Output needs to be bound on the component it's Outputed on, namely `page-search-modal` (according to your code). i.e.

```
<page-search-modal (updateSearchResults)='updateSearchResults($event)'>
// Here is my search bar.
</page-search-modal
```

Comment: But in my header call I already have one

`<page-header (updateSearchData) = 'updateSearchData ($ event)'> </ page-header>`

Nothing happens if I leave it this way:

`<page-header (updateSearchResults) = 'updateSearchResults ($ event)' (updateSearchData) = 'updateSearchData ($ event)'> </ page-header>`

PD: I tried it, and it did not work for me.

Comment: @Faber_Hozz it shouldn't be on your `page-header`, it should be on your `page-search-modal` - where you defined it the output. Your code as it stands wouldn't work - if that's not the code you actually have then we can't really help you. :\